# CD-DVD drive won't eject

Tags: optical-drive, eject

I have an Amilo Pa 1538 Fujitsu Siemens Laptop. For two years it has given me all sorts of problems like overheating etc.

Here is what happened this time: With the computer turned off, I pushed the eject button and the CD-DVD drive opened normally. After shaking the Laptop though, the drive fully opened and couldn't close normally, I had to push it in and found some resistence.

Now it won't eject! Indeed I press the eject button, the green light flashes and beeps for a second. Then nothing happens. I have tried the paperclick trick but either I don't do it correctly or it doesn't work.

Keep in mind that there is no CD in the drive.

Comment: Uh...Why did you shake the laptop?

Comment: The problem with the Laptop was a black screen. When I turned it on, the BIOS screen wouldn't appear. Last time that I happened I removed the battery, pressed the power button for 30sec and shook the laptop a little. This time however I had forgotten that the drive was already open :(

Answer (score 5):

It should open if you put in the pin. This is strange. Sometimes, you will have to move the clip in various directions to get it open. See if that helps.

In any case, I think the drive is dead and it's time to get a replacement.